# The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, jsp

I want to print the string value returned from the function.

But I get the error, even for this simple process.

Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /beansal.jsp
The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)
13: </head>
14: <body>
15: <%String s = new DBConnectionTest().Test();%>
16: <%=System.out.println(s)%>
17: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"></jsp:getProperty>&nbsp;
18: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="lastName"></jsp:getProperty>
19: </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At you code:
`16: <%=System.out.println(s)%>`

This would be 
`16: <%=s %>`

because it is interpreted as `<% out.print(s) %>`.

Comment: I do it.Error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /beansal.jsp at line 16

13: </head>
14: <body>
15: 
16: <%=new DBConnectionTest().Test()%>
17: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"></jsp:getProperty>&nbsp;
18: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="lastName"></jsp:getProperty>
19: </body>

Comment: DBConnectionTest is under any package?

Comment: Add.. `<%@ page import="mypackage.DBConnectionTest" %>` . Classes which are not under any package, jsp sometimes cant find it.